# Why IE does not refresh the page after a JS call to a click button?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

On a ASP.Net page, I am in front of a problem only with IE. Here is the description.

On a page, there is two buttons and one label. The first button is visible and calls a JS function on the click event. This JS function calls the click function of the second button. The second button has an C€ event handler on the click event. The C# event handler edit the label.

In Firefox : the label is correctly edited after the clicks.
In IE (8) : the label is not edited, despite the C€ event handler has been correctly hit.

Also, I observed, in IE, that the Page_Load event is called two times after the JS button click :
Page_Load
button2_OnClick => change of the Label Text
Page_Load => The Label Text is reset :(

In Firefox, the Page_Load is called only once.

My question is : how to make IE refresh correctly the page as Firefox does after a JS button click ?

Below is the sample test code :

1) Page ASPX

```html
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function button1Click(sender, args) {
            var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
            button2.click();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button1" Text="Click-me!" OnClientClick="button1Click();" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button2" Text="Second" OnClick="button2_OnClick" style="display:none" />
        <p />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1" Text="Init" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

2) C# code-behind :

```cs
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void button2_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Changed";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID of your button will not be button1 or button2 when it's rendered. It will probably be something like ctl001_button1. Therefore your javascript will not work. In ASP.NET 4 you can override this behaviour by using an assigned [ClientID](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx).

```
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button1" Text="Click-me!" 
           OnClientClick="button1Click();" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button2" Text="Second" 
           OnClick="button2_OnClick" style="display:none" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

As an aside, this alludes to the main problem with ASP.NET Winforms - it tricks developers into thinking that the web is a connected environment.

What actually happens when you click an `<asp:Button />` element by default is that a *postback* is invoked. I.e. Your browser sends a request to the server for a new page. It sends up something called *ViewState* which is how the server knows what you've done and what to render. There is no "event" handled as such.

Comment: I'm using ASP.Net 3.5, so I can't use that. Also the button1 and button2 are rendered as the same ID in the final client page, not as something like ctl001_button1.

Comment: I added an interesting info in the first post : "Also, I observed, in IE, that the Page_Load event is called two times after the JS button click [...]".

Comment: Try putting a `return false` in your `button1Click()` method.

Comment: Right answer David Neal !
What I tried successfully :
- put : OnClientClick="return button1Click();"
- put a return false at the end of the button1Click function.

And that's ok then. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the way you are trying to get the hidden button

```
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
```

maybe change this to

```
var button2 = document.getElementById("<%= button2.ClientID %>");
```

After the buttons are rendered in the browser, the ID is changed by the ASP.Net engine, and not the same as your source.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but that didn't solve the problem, because the button2 was already correctly retrieved, and the click method was correctly called.

Comment: **Doh**, I read the updates in the previous post. But why the first button is a asp.net control bothers me, really you should replace it with a html input button, and call the javacript from there.

Comment: What exactly though are you trying to Achieve?